# How to prove the conversion from a compete binary tree to an array?

Tags: arrays, data-structures, heap, binary-tree, heapsort

A **complete** binary tree can be efficiently implemented as an array, where a node at index i has children at indexes **2i** and **2i+1** and a parent at index **floor(i/2)**, with **one-based indexing**.

If child index is greater than the number of nodes, the child does not exist.

I see these conversions every but there is **no formal proof of them**, can any give a strict proof or a link to it, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this link [Derivation of index equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap#Derivation_of_index_equations) This is for 0 based indexing. But also has notes on 1 based indexing

Comment: Beautiful proof! I caught the key point: number of nodes on a full level **L** is almost **2** times the number of nodes on all its previous levels **from 0 to L-1**, that's why we have the **2** in the expression **2*i+ 2**.